# Was bedeutet "und zwar immer wieder"

Tags: meaning

Ich kann nicht verstehen, wie man "zwar" nutzt, und was "und zwar immer wieder" bedeutet.

EDIT:

Originale satz ist: "Gesucht wird ein Polizistenmörder - gefunden wird James Tully aus Pennsylvania. Und zwar immer wieder" (von: http://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/doppelgaenger-leidet-unter-dauerfestnahmen-101.html)

Comment: Can you elaborate where your problems are, for example with examples? Right now, you might as well have asked for how to use *though* in English. Can you also give a context for “zwar immer wieder”? Without context, this is just a sequence of words.

Comment: The parse tree is "[(und zwar)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/und_zwar) [(immer wieder)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/immer_wieder)".

Comment: @RegDwight: Nicht notwendigerweise, es könnte auch aus einem Satz wie »Es kommt zwar immer wieder mal vor, dass …$ stammen.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft It's hard to find such a counterexample also including *und*, though.

Comment: @Grantwalzer: Schon, aber das ist ja eben nicht unbedingt gegeben.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Achso... er muss sich wohl auf die Phrase aus der Überschrift bezogen haben.

Comment: @Grantwalzer: Aaah. Ich sollte mir wirklich angewöhnen in solchen Fällen auch den Fragetitel erneut zu lesen. Merke: Niemals Informationen nur im Titel verstecken (nicht dass ich da selbst unschuldig wäre).

Comment: Ich habe die komplett Satz einschreiben

Answer (score 5):

The core part of the phrase is

> und zwar

which is preceded by some statement, and followed by a specification of this statement:

> Unser Hund läuft davon, und zwar immer wieder.
>   *Our dog runs away, and frequently at that.*

---

Note that *zwar* can be used in another way (without the *und*):

> Das Auto ist zwar schön, aber dennoch viel zu teuer.
>   *Admittedly, the car is beautiful, but too expensive nonetheless.*
>   Das ist zwar unhöflich, doch oftmals notwendig.
>   *Even though it's impolite, it's often necesary.*

The first example grants some positive attribute, but rejects the whole.
The second acknowledges some negative attribute, but accepts the whole.